# Show escape characters in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to show escape characters (like "new line") in Visual Studio Code?

I was used to write code in Atom and it's feature of displaying whitespace characters automatically show this type of chars:

[Whitespace chars in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCtmv.png)

I'm already using the "editor.renderWhitespace : true" setting in VS Code, but it only shows me the space characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

v1.3.0 does not implement this feature.

Here is the [request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/13808184-display-carriage-return-cr-endofline-eol-l)

These settings are available in workspace settings:

```
    "editor.renderWhitespace": true,
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
```

Comment: Actual values for `editor.renderWhitespace` are `'none', 'boundary'`, and `'all'`.  

Tested in version 1.7.1. works as expected; you can see FS(Field Separator), US(Unit Separator), ETX(End of Text), and so on.

Comment: @VictorBarrantes doesn't show NUL, which is strange since it is a part of the ASCII control character scheme.